# AWS-SDK - making sure file paths are unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a `Project` model which `has_many :attachments`.

In the attachment model I have the following code:

```
has_attached_file :document, default_url: "",
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id: "...",
    secret_access_key: "..."
  },
  bucket: "projects",
  path: ":id/:filename"
```

Is `path: ":id/:filename"` enough to create a uniqe path? I can't find what options are available for `path`.

Answer (score 0):

If for every record in the attachments table you can have only one AWS key, the :id on its own is sufficient for uniqueness.

You might consider whether you want to obfuscate the URLs for the files with a hash as well, though, or the URLs become predictable. That may not be desirable.